# How alternately give value from one array to another js

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I need to set  different style.background for every element of array N1 taking style from array N2, `forEach()` method doesn't work correctly, because it returns for every element similar value. Also I try to put i++ for All_imagesExtanded arr, but it just put final item as a value of style. I Don't know what to do.

```
let all_imagesExtanded = new Array(
    "url(portfolio/inLake.jpg)",
    "url(portfolio/train.jpg)",
    "url(portfolio/tree.jpg)",
    "url(assets/portfolio/window_and_girl.jpg)",
    "url(assets/portfolio/window_and_girl.jpg)",
    "url(assets/portfolio/window_and_girl.jpg)",
)

let example =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.example_content'))
console.log(example)
example.forEach(function(elem){
    
    elem.style.backgroundImage= all_imagesExtanded
    
})
```

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For instance, add the current result you get and add also the expected Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that `example` and `all_imagesExtanded` have the same length and you want to assign values by index, you can use `index` param inside `forEach`:

```
example.forEach(function(elem, index){
    
    elem.style.backgroundImage = all_imagesExtanded[index]
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Second argument of `.forEach` callback function is the index that you can use to refer to the url inside the first array. Just make sure both arrays are of the same lengths.

```js
example.forEach(function(elem, index){
    
    elem.style.backgroundImage = all_imagesExtanded[index]
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

 No need to convert to querySelectorAll to Array.

 Access styles from array by index. (`all_imagesExtanded[i]`)

```js
const N2 = ["red", "green"];

document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((ele, i) => {
  ele.style.color = N2[i];
});
```

```html
<div class="box"> one </div>
<div class="box"> two </div>
```